# How to center items in horizonal subnav

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 nav that that works fine except that I cannot figure out how to get the dropdown items into a horizontal subnav whose items centered on the page instead of flush left.

Here's my existing code:

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>

  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>

    <!-- Dropdown -->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown link
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<br>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Navbar With Dropdown</h3>
  <p>This example adds a dropdown menu in the navbar.</p>
</div>
```

Here's what I would like the menu to look like when a top-level nav link is pressed.

[image: Of particular importance is that the subnav links are centred]

I have been able to get close to this but am having particular difficulty in centering the items in the red subnav.

This what I have that is closer:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333; 
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-content a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}

.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">About <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#company">Company</a>
      <a href="#team">Team</a>
      <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Services <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
      <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
      <a href="#package">Package</a>
      <a href="#express">Express</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Partners <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div style="padding:0 16px">
  <h3>Subnav/dropdown menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
  <p>Hover over the "about", "services" or "partners" link to see the sub navigation menu.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Still can't figure out how to center text in subnav - again 
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe share your 'close to' attempt so folks helping don't have to start from scratch?

Comment: You are not going to like the way this has to be done, due to the markup / CSS that bootstrap is using.  The overrides, and the way to "force" it into place is not good.  I'd recommend using alternate syntax / markup to get this working the way you want.

Comment: I updated my 'close to' attempt as suggested - at bottom of original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works but it can be a little tedious. I've wrapped the drop-down items in a div and gave them each their own unique class and a "center" class. Their unique classes set their width, and the center class centers them using auto margins. Here is the edited code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .subnav {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .subnav .subnavbtn {
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover,
    .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .subnav-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      background-color: red;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .subnav-content a {
      float: left;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .subnav-content a:hover {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .subnav:hover .subnav-content {
      display: block;
    }

    /* NEW CSS STARTS HERE */
    
    .center {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .about {
      width: 261px;
    }
    
    .services {
      width: 336px;
    }
    
    .partners {
      width: 299px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">About <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
      <div class="subnav-content">
        <div class="center about">
          <a href="#company">Company</a>
          <a href="#team">Team</a>
          <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Services <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
      <div class="subnav-content">
        <div class="center services">
          <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
          <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
          <a href="#package">Package</a>
          <a href="#express">Express</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subnav">
      <button class="subnavbtn">Partners <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
      <div class="subnav-content">
        <div class="center partners">
          <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
          <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div style="padding:0 16px">
    <h3>Subnav/dropdown menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
    <p>Hover over the "about", "services" or "partners" link to see the sub navigation menu.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want it to span the entire width of the screen but if you want to just have them be organized in a row instead of a column you can add a bootstrap **d-flex** to not have it be in the default display:block

```
      <div class="dropdown-menu d-flex">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
```